# Adding role claims - should i use the IClaimsTransformer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, .net-core, claims-based-identity, authorize-attribute

We would like to add a lot of role claims to the current principal (we use the `Authorize(Roles)` attribute), and found the `IClaimsTransformer` that looks like a perfect fit.

We've registerd it like this

```c#
 app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
        {
            Transformer = new GetRolesFromDatabaseClaimsTransformer(new RoleManager2(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ourcoolapp")))
        });
```

And the transform is like this:

```c#
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
{
        // A hacky way to not load on all requests. Better ideas?
        if (!context.Context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api/"))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
        }

        var roleClaims = RoleManager.GetRolesForUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name).Select(roleName => new Claim("role", roleName));

        var claims = new List<Claim> { };
        var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        claims.AddRange(identity.Claims);
        claims.AddRange(roleClaims);

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "local");
        var userPrinicpal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        return Task.FromResult(userPrinicpal);
}
```

Question: Are there alternative, or smarter ways of adding the role claims?

Thanks

Larsi

Comment: kindly FYI : `ClaimsTransformationContext` is not in ASP Core 2.0.0 and `ClaimsTransformer` isn't middleware anymore.To use ClaimsTransformation, register it in the service collection. for more info follow [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1454#issuecomment-332486093).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Another option could be [UserClaimsPrincipalFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userclaimsprincipalfactory-2)**

It provides methods to create claims principal for a given user and you can customize it just like `ClaimsTransformer`.

By default It adds `UserName` and `UserId` to claim collection.
In order to customize it you can driver from `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` and override `CreateAsync`

```c#
public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<User> userManager,
        RoleManager<Role> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
        ILogger<AppClaimsPrincipalFactory> logger) 
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("AppClaimsPrincipalFactory ctor");
    }

    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new []
        {
            new Claim("Foo", "Bar"), 
        });

        return principal;
    }
}
```

And Register the Factory in DI:

```c#
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>,  AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

It will change/override the claim whenever the user's claims requested.
For more info take a look at source at [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/eb3ff7fc32dbfff65a1ba6dfdca16487e0f6fc41/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs).

Comment: @Larsi - and other option is customizing UserStore and implement GetClaimsAsync but in this case claims stores in cookie, that has it's owns pros and coins, if you're interested I'll write practical sample in next Answer ;)

Comment: Consider that the difference between ClaimsTransformer and UserClaimsPrincipalFactory is that in ClaimsTransformer you change the claims on the fly (in every request) but in other cases you customize it for first time the identity(SignInManager) request for claims and after that claims save in the cookie ;)